# Div not adjusting in landscape mode on the phone

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I put a background photo taking 100% height.

When I open the site by mobile phone (or Chrome / Firefox console) in landscape mode, the image background does not take up all the space.

In desktop mode and mobile mode in portrait position they are ok. Only LANDSCAPE so that is a problem.

I want in landscape mode, the content is set the viewport. How to do this?

[image] MOBILE: MODE PORTRAIT, OK.

[image] MOBILE: MODE LANDSCAPE, The content does not fit within the main div and comes out of it.

Please, open the Snippet in the browser console. In cell simulator on landscape mode to see what I mean.

```css
body, html {
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;

}
.block {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;

}

.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;      
}

.centered {
  margin-top: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 500px; 
  background: white;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
     
    <div class="centered">
    
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/HP_logo_630x630.png" class="img-responsive" id="img_logo">
 <p style="color: black"> <a style="font-size:35px;"> xxxxxx</a> <br><br>text text <br> address <br>  </p>      
   </div>
  </div>
```

I try remove **.block:before** and:

```
@media(orientation: landscape){
  .background-image {
    min-height: 200%;
  }
}
```

But, this effect not works ONLY IN MODE MOBILE. It is works in MOBILE and DESKTOP. I want that it is works ONLY in mobile.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean... Your image is just set to be it's regular height. And your black background fills up the whole height.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please, see again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain that this is what you're looking for, but you can try changing "height" to "min-height" in ".block"

```
.block {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
}
```

This will ensure that the black background of the .block div continues to the end.